# Fetch 5 or 10 of the data | ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

I'm trying to make a search input, when the user types it show the fetching data, now I'm fetching all the data from the api, but I want to fetch the first 5 or 10 data only, and when the user types something it shows the rest of the data.

**The Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Table2 = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('/posts')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <tr key={post._id}>
            <td>{post.title}</td>
            <td>{post.username}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table2;
```

My question is how to fetch only 5 or 10 not the all data?

Comment: That something that needs to be supported by the API you're calling, e.g. `/posts?max_results=5`

Comment: Can you post the controller handling the `/posts` route on the backend?

Comment: @lpizzinidev https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-maxwell-ir1srt?file=/posts.js

Comment: @goto that's will work on all the app which I don't want it to, I'm fetching all the posts on Home page, but I want to fetch only 5 on Search page only